# How to Mock or SpyOn an exported function in React

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that's a default export

```
// Component.js
export default () => <>getData()</>;
export const getData = async () => await fetch('/');
```

```
// Component.test.js
import Component from 'Component'

describe('test getData', () => {
    const getDataMock = jest.spyOn(Component, 'getData');
    expect(getDataMock).toBeCalledOnce();
})
```

I get error:  Cannot spy the getData property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

Comment: just curious - why not move the `getData` into its own file?

Comment: Because it's only related to Component and is pretty small. I don't think every function should be it's own file.

Comment: What is `QueuesTable`? Where do you even try to `spy` on `getData` that results in the error?

Comment: Error during copy, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you imported the default function instead of getData.

```
// Component.test.js
import mydefault, * as notdefaults from 'Component';

test('test getData', () => {
    const getDataMocked = jest.spyOn(notdefaults, 'getData');
    getDataMocked.mockResolvedValue('hello!');
    expect(mydefault()).toBeDefined(); // call the default component to trigger getData()
    expect(getDataMocked).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```